# Wikimedia SVG not displaying

Tags: xml, svg, wikipedia

I'm wondering if something is wrong with this SVG file since I can not view it in Firefox or Chrome: [Map of Texas Highlighting Tarrant County](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Map_of_Texas_highlighting_Tarrant_County.svg).

Comment: Also, here's a [link to the Wikipedia page with a PNG of the SVG file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_Texas_highlighting_Tarrant_County.svg)

Comment: I can view it in firefox. It does, as David said, have 141 errors.

Comment: I can see the red fill in Firefox, but none of the paths. Is it the same for you? [Link to pic.](http://img.skitch.com/20101110-cyshe2fbjt8u8jhgj52xd6p3wq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has [141 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Map_of_Texas_highlighting_Tarrant_County.svg&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)